# Can I retrieve android files from my debug phone?

Tags: android

So my laptop has seriously crashed & i REALLY need my android working files (not backed up)

Is there any way I can get the app from my debug phone into android studio (in another laptop) & have them as working android files - pleaseee help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's your own application and you own copyrights, you can use some tools for decompiling Android apk. Quick google gave me [this](http://www.decompileandroid.com/).

or you can have a look at [Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file?rq=1)